# How do I redefine the __COPYRIGHT__ macro in Xcode 5?

Tags: templates, xcode5, copyright-display

The default Xcode 5 Cocoa Touch .h file template starts like this:

```
//
//  ___FILENAME___
//  ___PROJECTNAME___
//
//  Created by ___FULLUSERNAME___ on ___DATE___.
//___COPYRIGHT___
//
```

I want to redefine the `___COPYRIGHT___` macro. This macro itself seems to expand to something like:

```
Copyright (c) 2014 ___ORGANIZATIONNAME___. All rights reserved.
```

I want to change that expansion.

*Note that I do **not** want to change the definition of `___ORGANIZATIONNAME___` (which you can do from the File Inspector when you click on the Xcode project file in the navigator.)*

Answer (score 0):

Try running this in your terminal:

> $ defaults write com.apple.Xcode PBXCustomTemplateMacroDefinitions '{"COPYRIGHT"="**frasnian**";}'

You might want to change the "frasnian" part, though :)